# How to install rust built from source to different prefix?

Tags: rust

How do you `x.py install` rust built from git source to a prefix other than `/usr/local`?

I tried:

```
git/rust> python x.py install --prefix=/my/prefix
```

but it doesn't work:

```
error: Unrecognized option: 'prefix'
```

Answer (score 1):

The `--prefix` option is in the `configure` command that generates `x.py`.  So its like:

```
git/rust> configure --prefix=/my/prefix
git/rust> python x.py install
```